# GPS or ACCELEROMETER which is better to calculate the racing track?

Tags: android, gps, accelerometer

I want to develop an app for joggers to calculate there distance and speed .

Through searches I came to know that there are two things gps or accelerometer and accelerometers are cheaper than GPS to use.

I am new in android so how can I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know where the myth comes from but with accelerometer you cannot measure spped and distance for more than some seconds. (The reason is the double integration which introduces horrible errors)
So only GPS works.

Answer (score 0):

Accelerometer measures in 3-dimensions i.e. x, y and perpendicular direction(z axis). It often take input while moving phone from top to bottom . For an instance assume you are standing idle and moving your phone from top to bottom your 3D Accelerometer will still take input from the perpendicular direction (z axis).

So in my opinion though GPS will consume more battery but would be more efficient than Accelerometer in terms of precison and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

The maths and the rounding errors will kill your accuracy using the accelerometer.  You want distance; it provides the second differential of distance with respect to time.  You have to perform approximate numerical integration.  Twice.  Then you have all the degrees-of-freedom issues to contend with.  GPS will give you absolute position within the accuracy of your device and sampling rate.